# How to properly close connection to access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, garbage-collection, database-connection

At the moment our code looks like this

```
   public void Close(bool saveChange)
    {
        if ((_Connection != null) && (_Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
        {

            _Connection.Close();
            _Connection.Dispose();
            _Connection = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Where GC.Collect() is needed to close file properly and remove all .ldb files.
Is it possible to close db file and immideately remove all temp .ldb files without calling GC ?

Comment: Are you asking or telling? If this is not a question, it shouldn't be posted as one.

Comment: and what is the problem? Can you rephrase the question or point out the aspect that doesn't behave the way you'd like it to?

Comment: Fired for calling GC.Collect and coming up with a hogwash explanation why it is needed. Seriously. IT IS NOT LIKE THAT.

Comment: I hope you will find a new job, Tom

Comment: I believe @TomTom means _you_ got fired UP about this.

Comment: Yes. This is one of the most ridiculous statements about GC.COllect in years. And there is a LOT of stuff juniors make up instead of reading.

Comment: It was written by a guy with 7 years of experience. And yeah, I'm a junior who is asking how it could be changed in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Class that is using the Data in several entry-points.
and you HAVE to keep the connection open.
(hence can not use **using(Connection x=...){}** statement)

.

your class should also inherit IDisposable and implement

```
void Dispose()
{
  this.dbConnection.Dispose();
}
```

the dbConnection.Dispose() will take care of closing the connection gracefully unless you need some custom actions performed (e.g. Logout, Save Cached Info, Etc...)

Anyway, i am in favor of @Tim Schmelter idea:

1. Close the connection after any transaction.
2. The Connections will be cached in the Connection Pool => insignificant performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

As every class implementing [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), you should use the [`using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose objects. On this way connections are also getting closed.

For example:

```
using(var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Pets/Pets.mdb")))
{
     conn.open();
     // do something with it
}
```

You should also read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic5) because the way you're using connections can be improved.
As a rule of thumb: always create,open,use and close connections at the same place and let the [ADO.NET connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) manage the underlying connections.

Comment: Actually that was the reason to use GC. Default connection pool behavior looks a bit unpredictable. If there is need to delete/rename db file right after closing connection, temporary .ldb files cause problems

Comment: @Ask: Then have a look at this answer (or the others there) to find a solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016027/284240

Answer (score 1):

Calling *GC.Collect()* may not be the best solution, as this method collects all the "garbage". You may find it very helpful to make use of the `using` keyword. e.g.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here.
}
```

Just right after your using block, the connection object will be disposed!

using **connections**, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254507%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**using** keyword, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually calling GFC.Collect is unproductive as it blocks GC statistic colelction and ahs serious negative side effects.

Comment: ldb file still exists in such case for some unpredictable amount of time

Answer (score 0):

connection.Close();
OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();

This solved it for me eventually